# Laravel relations, select next raleted row from database.

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-query-builder

I have related items in my database. I selected all of items from database by related id:

```
$next_stock = $this->model->get()->where('part_id', $in_data['part_id'])->all();
```

and I collection of rows grouped by one specific id, like on the picture. All of them selected by "part_id":

[Selection Of Items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PSsjf.png)

[Grouped By Same Id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1aDUX.png)

Also with this line of code i can select one of the items from this collection:

`$next_stock = $this->model->get()->where('id', $old_stock['id'])->where('part_id', $in_data['part_id'])->first();`

But how can I select the following items after this one?
Or, how can I select second or third item from this collect?

I cannot just increase id number by one from first, because sometimes this item ids not following each other.

Comment: why don't you use `get()` instead of `first` and `loop` through the results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having a collection, you can take a specific element in the position with a combination of `take()` and `last()`.

```
$collection = $this->model->get()->where('part_id', $in_data['part_id'])->all();
$second = $collection->take(2)->last(); //if this doesnt work, do it in 2 steps
$third  = $collection->take(3)->last(); //if this doesnt work, do it in 2 steps
```

If you don't have a collection, take directly from database like this

```
$second = $this->model
->where('part_id', $in_data['part_id'])
->skip(1)
->first();
```

If it doesn't work with `first()`

```
$collect = $this->model
->where('part_id', $in_data['part_id'])
->skip(1)
->take(1)
->get();

$second = $collect->first();
```

**Edit**

skip() and take() are actually part of the query builder, not eloquent model. So it won't work with Eloquent in Laravel 5.4

Try with

```
$collect = $this->model
->where('part_id', $in_data['part_id'])
->get(1); //For the second record, 0 being the first
```

Comment: It is gives me error:
Method skip does not exist.

or:

Call to a member function take() on array

Comment: Skip exists only in Eloquent. So you should use Eloquent like `$collect = Model::where()->skip()->take()->get();` I have no idea what `this->model` refers to

Comment: This is refers to Price model.

`public function __construct(Price $price, Inventory $inventory) {
        $this->model = $price;
        $this->inventory = $inventory;
    }`

Comment: Ok, for this to work, use `Price::where()...` instead of this->model. Because the model you pass is already an object, therefore cannot be filtered. You can only use these methods in collections.

Comment: Changed, it gives the same error, for both methods `skip()` and `take()` as it was before.

Comment: skip() and take() are actually part of the query builder, not eloquent model. So it won't work with Eloquent.

Comment: Ok check my last edit. Unfortunately this is going to be my last contribution for tonight. It's 2AM in Sydney. If it still doesn't work, please follow this link and try variations of the functions they offer to see if you can get it to work. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/collections

Comment: Thank you very much @EddyTheDove, all works now.
Here is the lines that i was looking for

`$price_collection = $this->model->get()->where('part_id', $in_data['part_id']);

$next_stock = $price_collection->take(2)->last();`

You helped to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't doing it yet, you should set your model's relationships.
E.g. If you use "one-to-many", Eloquent will automatically determine the proper foreign key column on the model for you.

```
$parts = App\Stock::find(1)->partId;

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    //
}
```